# How to prove that $f(x)=x^7+7x^2+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How to prove that $f(x)=x^7+7x^2+2$is  irreducible  over  $\mathbb{Q}$?

I have tried to   use Eisenstein's Criterion. I pick $-2$,since
$$(-2)^7+7(-2)^2+2\equiv 0~~ (\mod 7)$$
Let $y=x-2$,then

$$f(x)=g(y)=-98 + 420 x - 665 x^2 + 560 x^3 - 280 x^4 + 84 x^5 - 14 x^6 + x^7.$$

We see that $7\mid a_i$,$i=0,1,\cdots,6$,$7\nmid a_7=1$,but unfortunately $7^2\mid a_0=-98$,so $g(y)$ isn't an Eisenstein polynomial.

Comment: Perhaps try $y=x+2$. Maybe it can work.

Comment: Be careful ending sentences with a number and then an exclamation mark. You do not mean that the constant term is $98!$, right?

Comment: @Anurag A It turns out $158 + 476 x + 679 x^2 + 560 x^3 + 280 x^4 + 84 x^5 + 14 x^6 + x^7$

Comment: @mbfkk which isn't an Eisenstein polynomial.

Comment: @ Arthur Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: There are clearly no linear factors, and I think (needs checking) that mod $3$ there are no quadratic factors either (there are only three quadratic irreducibles to check). So if it's not irreducible it's a product of a cubic irreducible and a degree 4 irreducible. I would check how it factorises mod 2 (and also perhaps mod 3) to see if this is plausible   .

Comment: If my calculations are correct, you can Hensel lift the solution $x\equiv26\pmod{7^3}$ to a $7$-adic solution of $x^7+7x^2+2=0$, and so finding an Eisenstein criterion argument is hopeless. Maybe you can prove it's irreducible modulo some other prime?

Comment: In fact , the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_3$[$X$]

Comment: Excellent @Peter: did you do it by hand or machine?

Comment: To be honest , with PARI/GP ,  but there are not too many polynomials that have to be checked.